# How to split strings in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to split the datetime in the below object to date and time separately.

```
 let A = {
   datetime: '2019-02-01 15:30:43' 
 }
```

And save it in two different variables.

Comment: This is not react-native question. removing tag.Adding Javascript tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) e.g.

```
var splitString = A.datetime.split(" ");
// Returns array, ['2019-02-01','15:30:43']
```

You can access this with `splitString[0]` for the date and `splitString[1]` for the time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) library if you don't want any surprises.

```
moment(A.datetime).format('L'); // get date only

moment(A.datetime).format('LTS') // get time only.
```

You can have specific date and time format as well when using `momentjs`.

You may also use JavaScript's [Date class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for this.

```
const date = new Date(A.datetime);

//to get date
date.getDate() +' '+date.getMonth()+' '+date.getFullYear();

//to get time.
date.getHours()+' '+date.getMinutes()+' '+date.getSeconds();
```

Comment: Do I need to import anything else to get "moment().format()" to working ? I'm using this in a react-native project, that's why I'm asking

Comment: You just need to import moment. Which you can do like `import moment from 'moment'` providing you're using npm/yarn for your packages. Otherwise you can import it from the CDN.

Comment: @VinayNarayankutty check this home page. http://momentjs.com/docs/.They have given in details how to use

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN your time doesn't work, the method you need is `getSeconds()` not `getMilliseconds()` I have edited your answer, if you could peer review it that'd be cool.